# Bookmark/Mark as unread

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, information-display, research

In the interest of people using SO as a research resource/tool it would be good to be able to mark questions as "unread" instead of just star them. That way you can work through your list of "unread" questions in order to learn about certain topics you are interested in marking them as read when you're done. Stared questions are more useful for questions you really like and want to keep an eye on.

E.g. "I have no time ATM but a question I came across looks really interesting and I want to save it for future research."

Comment: Pretty good idea, however unread probably isn't the most accurate term.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to ask. I'd like to be able to bookmark questions.

Comment: @Jeff Why is this declined? I am trying to answer unanswered questions right now and it is a pain to not to be able to mark those I have already looked at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe have 2-3 different colored stars (like in GMail labs) that each person could then use according to his/her preferences. Multiple clicks on the star image would toggles between the colors and none.

Comment: Or on this site, 2-3 indistinguishably different shades of grey?

Comment: @Paul - love yr answer because of context (:>) 
Assaf: having multiple stars is more like rating something. Maybe very simple REMEMBER TO READ flag and having a list of flaged this way items in "StackExchange" panel on left side of site bar?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that users be able to mark a post (not just a whole question) as read (instead of unread).

All posts are initially marked *unread*. A post is marked as read on voting or commenting. It will also be possible to "vote neutral", neither up nor down, by clicking between the up- and downvote button, effectively marking the post as read. As soon as a post is edited, the "read" tag will be removed and the post is counted as unread again.

That's it for a single thread. To make this easy to use in practice, users will also be able to view a list of all unread posts in questions marked as favorite.

Comment: (as of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8878/mark-post-as-read-closed)

Answer (score 3):

What I want is the possibility for two kinds of marking **read**:

Mark read until further activity on the question.
Mark read forever.

This would lead to more answering on my part because I spend too much time wading through questions I have already looked at.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that what your browser bookmarks are for? Or de.li.ci.ous (or however it's spelled) or opening multiple tabs, or...? Does the site need to save your links for you? How is the "I want to read this later" problem unique to SO?