# A favorites star icon on the header

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, navigation

I frequently use favorites to mark questions that I need to keep a watch on, or look at later when I have time. The peeve is that they're inconvenient to access and I end up checking them infrequently.

A small star icon (near the envelope icon) that could show the "favorites" tab would be really useful to quickly begin browsing favorites, instead of having to visit the account page, etc.

Comment: +1. Also, being able to see which questions in a list of questions have been favorited would be nice (like if I favorite this question, I would see that I have favorited it when looking at the *Questions* list.)

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/450/bookmark-mark-as-unread/28019#28019

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a stop-gap, how about just a browser bookmark to [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41021?tab=favorites#sort-top).

Answer (score 0):

Would also love to see an icon like this, but which would present a list of new answers / comments / etc for the favourited question, similar to the way that the recent activity page works.