# Expose Ability to Favorite on the Questions Listing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, bookmarks

It'd be nice to be able to mark favorites from the list of questions rather than having to go into each question.

Comment: So from the snippet alone you can tell if you want to favourite a question?

Comment: I don't see the harm in marking them as favourites & then reviewing at a later date.

Comment: Another dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/450/bookmark-mark-as-unread

Comment: I don't think either of the "duplicates" are in fact duplicates of this request...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't do this for the same reason we don't allow voting from the question page; it's a conscious decision.

You have to click through to vote, because we don't believe you can cast an informed vote without viewing the full question and answer.

Similar rules would apply for favoriting.

Answer (score 1):

You already have this feature:
Hover with the mouse over the link, click your right mouse button and select "Bookmark this link".

Comment: ha ha.  Then why provide the favorites ability & tab, much less associate badges with the functionality...

Comment: @rexem: Honestly, I do not know.