# Marking a question as a favorite directly in the question list

Tags: feature-request, questions, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expose Ability to Favorite on the Questions Listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27951/expose-ability-to-favorite-on-the-questions-listing)

I would like to be able to favorite questions directly in the question list.

I can think of two situations where this would be handy:

1. If you see an interesting question, but don't necessarily want to have to visit the question (maybe because you don't have time right now or there are 0 answers)
2. If you see two (or more) interesting questions, and want to favorite them all before you read a question in it's entirety (maybe so you don't forget the others after your train of thought gets lost in the one question you read it it's entirety)

Can you think of more situations where this functionality would be a good thing?