# Hide viewed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Bookmark/Mark as unread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/450/bookmark-mark-as-unread)
>   [The Ability to Hide Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions)
>   [Hide a particular question locally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/hide-a-particular-question-locally)

Is it worth having the capability to hide questions that we've already viewed before? Perhaps only on the "Newest" tab and/or on the front page "Interesting" tab.

I know a lot of people (like me) visit SO very frequently and see the same questions over and over again that do not necessarily pertain to them. Hiding "new" questions that you've already viewed allows you to filter through the questions you've already deemed uninteresting to you and perhaps take a look at some older questions that may be more relevant.

The obvious downside to this is if you're looking for a question that you've seen before. But there are a number of ways around this such as:

1. Make the feature togglable
2. Make a new tab for this view (probably not a good idea as it clutters up the interface)
3. Making users use the favorite option to bookmark interesting questions (also not good because it forces a lot more work)

Comment: You *really* see the same questions over and over again? I don't think this has *ever* happened to me, considering the rate at which new questions get posted.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I guess it depends on the particular tag and time of day.

Comment: More of a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8878/mark-post-as-read-closed, but this was closed as duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/450/bookmark-mark-as-unread