# Filter "read questions"

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide a particular question locally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/hide-a-particular-question-locally)
>   [Hide viewed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100626/hide-viewed-questions)

I expect this feature had already been suggested, but I can't find it in a search... so maybe not.

I would like the ability to view "Unread" messages on the Questions page.  I guess I would see this as another tab to go along with **newest**, **featured**, **faq**, **votes**, **active**, and **unanswered**.  And it would simply show any questions I had not yet viewed (probably sorted by newest first).

As optional expansions on this idea:

- An option to mark a question as 'unread' when viewing the question
- The option to show any questions with unread answers as well as unread questions.

While this feature would be pretty worthless (at least to me, although I suspect to anyone) on SO, on some of the smaller sites, it would make reading far more efficient.  I usually do a good job of keeping up by reading the 'newest' tab, but I'm gone for a day or two, it is sometimes hard to catch up again.

Comment: I'm not interested really in _hiding_ questions... I still would like them to show up in searches and on the other pages where they exist now.  I just want the ability to see only the questions I haven't already read in one place, too.