# hiding reviewed questions

Tags: feature-request

There are a lot of questions which I read once and come up with a decision I never want to look at it again. I'd like to mark them such a way so they get at least ghosted - like for ignored tags; better hidden out of my sight. Am I missing a tiny control anywhere? Should we have a one, an opposite of the "like" star?

Comment: It is not the responsibly of the site to *hide* any questions from anyone... If you don't want to see that post again... don't click on it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Ability to Hide Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions), [Hide viewed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100626) (and the duplicates therein)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a particular question locally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/hide-a-particular-question-locally)